# Typo3 9.5 UrlLinkHandler

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I'm trying to use the UrlLinkHandler in Typo3 9.5. So far I've configured my Backend with TCEMain.

```
TCEMAIN.linkHandler.youtube {
    handler = TYPO3\CMS\Recordlist\LinkHandler\UrlLinkHandler
    label = Youtube
}
```

This works fine so far and I can add links within the RTE.
For rendering the Link in the frontend my Typoscript looks like this:

```
config {
     recordLinks.youtube {
        typolink {
            wrap = test|test
        }
    }
}
```

But the frontend just shows a regular rendered anchor tag like `<a href="http://domain.tld" target="_blank">Link</a>`.

Any hints what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Small hint: The link seems not to be saved in a correct way in the backend. Documentation (https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/9.5/en-us/ApiOverview/LinkBrowser/Linkhandler/Index.html) says "The links are now stored in the database with the syntax <a href="t3://record?identifier=anIdentifier&amp;uid=456">A link</a>." While testing, I got a "<a href="t3://page?uid=456">". Generating a record link via TypoScript is working fine.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that before but with no effect. The generated link is just the a href.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oehm, you're mixing up different things... You register a new `UrlLinkHandler` for BE, but your `recordLinks`-block for FE is a part of the `RecordLinkHandler`.

If you want to have a link-type formatted in a special (like you described on [typo3.net](https://www.typo3.net/forum/thematik/zeige/thema/128526/)), then an own LinkHandler could be a solution.